# Flipper: Is it possible to get a timestamp for the most recent change to a feature?

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-6, flipper

Using Flipper (0.28.3) in Rails I want a way to detect when the most recent change to a feature. I want to do this so I can use it as part of a cache key to invalidate view caches whenever a change is made to flipper.

This has to include features being deleted.

We are using the flipper-active_record gem, and was hoping that `UPDATED_AT` on `FLIPPER_GATES` would reflect the changes I need. However this doesn't seem to leave any record of gates being removed or features being deleted.

Ideally I don't want to be storing the full state of Flipper and comparing with the current state, I also don't need to specialise this across different actors. I just need the latest change to Flipper, globally.

Is there a source for this? or a way to find it?